# Identity Manager w/ ASP.NET Identity HostSecurityConfiguration login

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

Implementing the `HostSecurityConfiguration` for Identity Manager, I have passed a `LoginPath` to a local route as a `CookieAuthenticationOption` (as per Brock's video).

However when i click the login button from Identity Manager I get a 401 and the browser is stuck on /identitymanager/authorize?`state=randomnumber&client_id=idmgr&response_type=token`

Any ideas?

Comment: Link to Brock's video?

Comment: https://vimeo.com/125427106

Answer (score 1):

I had my CookieAuthentication config declared in my OWIN startup after the identity manager config. Obvious when it was pointed out to me.